# Cross platform base64 byte array encoding

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, base64

I have a byte array that I generate on an android device, encode to base64, send to a server, then display on the web using JavaScript. However the byte arrays do not match.

example byte array:

```
-39,86,-91,26,77,98,-3,108,83,-108,-53,-8,-102,-39,-42,-106,-90,70,122,26,43,-46,82,124,-4,-116,-51,-92,100,-104,57,9,-127,0
```

android side encoding:

```
import android.util.Base64;

Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

resulting string:

```
2ValGk1i/WxTlMv4mtnWlqZGehor0lJ8/IzNpGSYOQmBAA==
```

javascript decoding:

```
var decoded = atob(encodedString);
var bytes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
    bytes.push(decoded.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

resulting byte array:

```
217,86,165,26,77,98,253,108,83,148,203,248,154,217,214,150,166,70,122,26,43,210,82,124,252,140,205,164,100,152,57,9,129,0
```

All numbers that should be negative have had 256 added to them. How do I fix this?

note: decoding it android side produces the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got around the problem by manually correcting it inside the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
    var currentChar = decoded.charCodeAt(i);
    if (currentChar < 128)
        bytes.push(currentChar);
    else 
        bytes.push(currentChar - 256);
}
```

I am still looking for the proper way to achieve this, if someone knows please post.